# Playstation 3 controllers won't connect or turn on even when connected via cable

Tags: ps3, controllers

All of a sudden both my PS3 controllers won't light up or connect even when directly connected with a cable.  I thought it might just be a dead battery but the controller wont' light up or turn on at all with different cables and power supplies.  I tested the cable as well.

Can I do something to troubleshoot?  It seems suspicious that both controllers would go on the fritz at the exact same time.

Comment: odd indeed that they would both die at the same time. I am assuming there was no power surges (having them connected to some other charging source or something) or sudden jolts of movement (like falling or something)...
The only troubleshooting that you have not already tried would be to physically swap out the batteries inside the controller for ones that you know to work.  ...i mean, you could take it apart and test all the wires that you could test with a digital multimeter. but it is likely that the bat. just died. (if it died hard enough it wouldnt work even on the cable) Would both

Comment: controllers get the same amount of use? (unlikely) Would they spend too long on the charger? (also unlikely to damage them) Would they spend too long in a nearly completely discharged state? (empty is bad for lithium ion, that's why they arrive from the factory with like 20% charge.) thats all i can think of, sorry. ...oh, and direct sunlight or excessive heat, will also both, be the death of batteries.

Comment: one would get more usage vs the other controller probably - but they both got fairly regular usage.  They were however very rarely charged fully - we've been bad about keeping them fully connected all the time

Comment: Still quite odd, are they getting along in age? Showing much signs of wear?

Comment: few years old but still look pretty good - it's an adult household with very light game playing so they look pretty new.  It was mostly used to navigate netflix and hulu apps.

Comment: I am also guessing that you tried resetting the controllers? With a paperclip? IF you are looking at the charging port thing in the "not quite back but sort of" of the controller. then follow that position downward. you will see a screw. follow that position to the right, and you should see a little bitty hole. That is the reset thing. Sony does a great job of pointing that out huh? Such hubris, "our controllers will never need to be reset, so why point out that you even can." pfff

Comment: That is of course assuming that you are talking about the sony dual shock 3 controller, and not some madcatz generic or something.